# Getting the rational function with given characteristics

Tags: self-learning, graphing-functions, rational-functions

> The curve C has an equation
>   $$y = \frac{ax^2+bx+c}{x+d},$$
>   where $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ are constants. The curve cuts the $y$-axis at $(0,-2)$ and has asymptotes $x=2$ and $y = x + 1$.

From a previous part of the question, I have obtained $d = -2$. I am now asked to obtain the values of $a$, $b$ and $c$. Here is what I have done,

First, I would find $c$ since I know the curve cuts the $y$ axis at $(0,-2)$
$$\begin{align} \frac{a(0)^2+b(0)+c}{0-2} & = -2 \\
                        \frac{c}{-2}      & = -2 \\
                                       c  & = 4
\end{align}$$

I do not know what to do next to find $a$ and $b$ but I tried to substitute $y = x+1$ into the equation of the curve and compared the coefficients but that did not work. Could someone please guide me how to do so? I find questions like these unusual since my textbook only showed how to find the asymptotes and graph such functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

$$
\lim_{x \to \infty}\dfrac{ax^2+bx+4}{x(x-2)}=1
$$
and
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty}\left[\dfrac{ax^2+bx+4}{x-2}-(x+1) \right]=0
$$

Comment: Thanks, I've got the values but could you please explain to me why is it done that way?

Comment: Loock at : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptote#Oblique_asymptotes  (in your case $m=1$ and $n=1$).